# How to group columns in an SWT table?

Tags: java, swt

I am using SWT `Table` widget.
I am trying to group columns grouping in SWT Table so please help me friend how to create column grouping in SWT table.

I have three column in a table: NAME, AGE and ADDRESS and the ADDRESS column should have sub-columns like CITY, STATE, etc.

```
| NAME | AGE |    ADDRESS   |
|      |     | CITY | STATE |
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean by 'column grouping'

Comment: Suppose I am create one column Address and sub column city, state,pincode ...

Comment: I have using 3 column in my table NAME, AGE and ADDRESS and now i am create  sub column in  ADDRESS column like City, State etc.

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

The SWT Table does not support column groups. You can use the [Nebula Grid](https://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php) instead if you really require this feature. See the [Snippets page](https://eclipse.org/nebula/snippets.php) for examples.

Comment: Hello Rudiger are sure SWT Table not support column grouping?

Comment: If the column grouping you have in mind should [look like this](https://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.png), it **cannot** be done with the stock SWT Table. Otherwise edit your question and explain in more detail what you need.